# php simple xml child node into a foreach

Tags: php, simplexml

I have an XML file. It looks like the following :

```
<Offers>
 <Offer>
  <OfferID>1</OfferID>
  <OfferName>Offer One</OfferName>
 </Offer>
 <Offer>
  <OfferID>2</OfferID>
  <OfferName>Offer Two</OfferName>
 </Offer>
</Offers>
```

I have a variable declared like below :

```
$latest_offers = simplexml_load_file("Offers.xml");
```

Now my problem is how i can get a out put like this :

```
foreach($offer as $item)
{
 echo <offerID>, <OfferName>...each and everything inside the offer nod
}
```

How can i achieve this. Tried a lot but no success.

Comment: Knowing what the simplexml_load_file()-method does would be nice...

Comment: @looper - Really!, `simplexml_load_file` is PHP function and not user defined.

Comment: @PushPesh - Oops, sorry for that. Awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php
$latest_offers = simplexml_load_file("Offers.xml");
foreach($latest_offers->Offer as $offer) {
   echo $offer->offerID . ', ' . $offer->OfferName . '<br>';
}
?>
```